# How can I access an object array located inside of another object which is then inside a superclass array?

Tags: java, arrays, casting, object

I have an abstract class `Employee`, and based on that, I created the following subclasses:

`FulltimeEmployee`
`PartTimeEmployee`
`Salesman`

as well as one standalone class, `Orders`.

I use the `Orders` class to "describe the salesman" by sending an array of orders in the Salesman constructor:

```
public Salesman(String firstname, String lastname,int code, String address,
                String city,int tk,int phone,String email,int deptcode,int card,
                double hours,String cat,int orderno,double salary,
                Orders[] order){
 super(  firstname, lastname, code,  address, city, tk, phone, email, deptcode,
         card, hours, cat );
 this.orderno=orderno;
 
 setBaseSalary( salary );
 getSalary(orders);
 /////////////////

 }
```

Later, I use that array to calculate the bonus a salesman gets, depending on the amount of sales he makes.

In `main`, I created an array of type `Employee`:

```
Employee employees[] = new Employee[ 7 ];
   employees[ 0 ] = salary1;
   employees[ 1 ] = salary2;
   employees[ 2 ] = salary3;
   employees[ 3 ] = partt1;
   employees[ 4 ] = partt2;
   employees[ 5 ] = sales1;
   employees[ 6 ] = sales;
```

where each row is a different type of employee (salary = full-time, partt = part-time, and sales = salesman).

My problem is that I want to print the orders of each salesman using the employees array.
What I've done so far is

```
for (int i=5;i<employees.length;i++){
              System.out.printf("Orders of Salesman: %S %S",
                  employees[i].getName(),employees[i].getSurname());
              System.out.printf(" Total amount(money) from orders: %,.0f ",
                  employees[i].earnings());
              int j=0;
              ((Salesman)employees[i]).getOrderNo(arr) ;
              //((Orders)employees[i]).getOrderNo();
              System.out.printf("ordernumber: %d  orderdate:%s  description: %s
                  order amount(money): %,.0f\n ");
                 
           }
```

The problem comes here:

`System.out.printf("ordernumber: %d  orderdate:%s  description: %s  order amount(money): %,.0f\n ");`

How do I access the orders array inside of the Salesman object on employees array?
I have tried casting, but it won't work because Orders is not a subclass of Employee.

I need it to print, for example,

> Orders of Salesman: john koun
>
> Total amount of orders: 13000
> Orders per Salesman
>
> Order number: 1 order date: 10/2/2010 description: machinery sale order amount: 12000
>
> Order number: 2 order date: 20/2/2010 description: sales of parts order amount: 1000

Comment: Please provide full listing for your `Salesman` class

Comment: note, the constructor argument is named `order` however you refer to it as `orders`. this code obviously won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `Salesman` constructor accepts an `Order[]` orders but it doesn't look like you keep a reference to it anywhere (unless you do that in `getSalary` or in the commented out portion).

You will need to add something like

`this.orders = orders;`

in your `Salesman` constructor so you can refer to the array as a field/property of the `Salesman` object.

Typically you should use the `Bean` pattern whereby each field has a getter/setter method:

```
public Order[] getOrders(){
    return orders;
}

public void setOrders(Order[] orders){
    this.orders=orders;
}
```

then in your constructor add `setOrders(orders);`

and then in your debug/output code add:

```
Salesman salesman = (Salesman) employees[i];
for (Order order : salesman.getOrders())
    System.out.println(order); // i don't know what fields order has!
```

Comment: Although your answer looks good to me, I would have tried to bring the OP to the solution by himself so that he improve his skills through normal learning process, since the question is tagged as `[homework]`.

Comment: No craftsman, but an excellent senior information and process systems consultant with a lot of teaching experience (no offense meant).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. This really helped me solve my problem, as i was not experienced enough in the use of casting. Also you were right about the this.orders = orders;. i totally forgot to put it in my constructor, which led to all the trouble later

Answer (score 0):

If what you're saying is that you have an array of `Employee`, and each `Salesman` (only) has a member that provides the orders himself has sold, then you have to work with an array of array.

At first view, your `Employee` array is more likely a vector, that is, a one dimensional array. Plus, your `Salesman` class has an `Order` array which also seems to be a vector. If this is what you actually got, you only have to iterate through your `Salesman.Orders` member to get the sales your `Salesman` did.

Since it is tagged as `[homework]`, I refuse to write the code and give you it all cooked for you.

Besides, here are some hints:

1. You already iterate through an array of `Employee`, so you know how to iterate through one;
2. You say that a `Salesman` derives from the `Employee` class, hence making `Employee` perhaps type-castable to `Salesman`, and then you shall get your instance of the `Salesman` class, it this actual `Employee` IS a `Salesman`, otherwise it should return null;
3. Now, you access your fields through property methods (getters and setters methods);

> So, how could you make `Orders` accessible from the outside of your class, and expose it as an array?
>
> If you've been able to expose it as an array, how do you iterate through an array to get each of the orders amount so that you may calculate how much this instance of `Salesman` has sold?

Comment: thank you so much!!!, i guess the answer was really infront of me the holetime! i forgot to set the orders object in my Salesman constructor(this.orders=order and then got troubled ans tucked upon something that  could easily be fixed if i looked at my code more carefully . I really apreciate your help, and your quick reply over my question